# find package name - Spring Boot library

Tags: spring-boot, modularity, component-scan

I'm making a library to be used with Spring Boot. This lib define some annotations that can be used in methods.

How can I find (at runtime) the package of the application where the library is being used?
I need this in order to scan for the annotated methods.

Comment: Do you want to create spring boot starters?

Comment: You can scan all the classes under @ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.name") like Spring does. Or provide another custom annotation to be added on the main class where client application using the library can use your custom annotation to declare which package to scan.

Comment: @codeMan only if necessary for this to work

Comment: @RajeshDwivedi how to do the first?

Comment: Spring has this code already. Please go through org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScanPackages class. It can provide much better insight how spring is handling it. You can align your implementation on same line .
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScanPackages.java#L146

Comment: Do you want to find packages at the initialization stage or after app launch?

Comment: @tsarenkotxt at the initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html):
 1. Using [ConfigurableListableBeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.html) you can iterate over [BeanDefinition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html)
 2. Determine if bean's `class` has *your* annotation
 3. Get the package from the bean's `class` name

Example:

```java
@Component
public class MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        Set<String> packages = findAnnotationUsagePackages(MyAnnotation.class, beanFactory);
        ...
    }

    private Set<String> findAnnotationUsagePackages(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass,
                                                    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        Set<String> annotationUsagePackages = new HashSet<>();

        for (String beanDefinitionName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            BeanDefinition beanDefinition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanDefinitionName);

            if (beanDefinition instanceof ScannedGenericBeanDefinition) {
                ScannedGenericBeanDefinition genericBeanDefinition = (ScannedGenericBeanDefinition) beanDefinition;

                if (AnnotationUtils.isCandidateClass(genericBeanDefinition.getBeanClass(), annotationClass)) {
                    String beanClassName = genericBeanDefinition.getBeanClassName();

                    if (beanClassName != null) {
                        annotationUsagePackages.add(ClassUtils.getPackageName(beanClassName));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return annotationUsagePackages;
    }

}
```

About the [AnnotationUtils.isCandidateClass()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#isCandidateClass-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-):

> Determine whether the given class is a candidate for carrying the specified annotation (at type, method or field level)

Also pay attention to the [AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanClass()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition.html#getBeanClass--):

> Throws: IllegalStateException - if the bean definition does not define a bean class, or a specified bean class name has not been resolved into an actual Class yet

P.S. also you can collect classes or meta-information inside `AnnotationUtils.isCandidateClass` condition block

Comment: my annotation applies only to methods, would it still work?

Comment: yes `AnnotationUtils.isCandidateClass(beanClass, myAnnotationClass)` will find your annotations that were specified on the methods (as stated in the documentation and I also checked it works)